# Error while compiling groovy code with java 11

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I am trying to compile groovy code with java 11 and getting the below error:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project xml: Compilation failure
Found 0 errors and 0 warnings
```

The same is working fine with java 8.
Any help on this would be appreciated.
This is the POM file being used.
I have updated the pom file with latest groovy versions i.e., 3.0.7 and the maven compiler version is 3.8.1

```
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.comcast.ted</groupId>
        <artifactId>TED</artifactId>
        <version>5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>xml</artifactId>
    <name>xml</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build> 
</project>
```

Comment: First I would suggest to upgrade your maven-compiler-plugin version to the most recent.

Comment: updated the maven compiler to the latest version ie., 3.8.1.. still getting the same error...

Comment: Please show full pom file and the code which has compile errors...

Comment: added the pom file in the original query

Comment: without the codes and the actual errors, it will be difficult to help you :)

Comment: I got it resolved by updating the groovy-all version, groovy-eclipse-compiler version and groovy-eclipse-batch version..